# Using the AM-GM to find the minimum of $x^2+(4-2x)^2$

Tags: inequality, means

I would like to get a min value of the parabola expression $x^2+(4-2x)^2$ with  AM-GM inequality. ($x$ is a real number)

$$x^2+(4-2x)^2\geq 2\sqrt{x^2(4-2x)^2 }$$ with equality when  $x^2=(4-2x)^2$.

But it gives a wrong value. Why can't we get a correct min value with AM-GM inequality although both $x^2$and $(4-x)^2$ are non negative real numbers?

Comment: $(4-2x)^2$ or $(4-x)^2$?

Comment: $(4-2x)^2$, I corrected the question. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is because the RHS is still an expression of $x$ rather than a definite number.

Comment: What is that "wrong value"?

Comment: You can see the desired minimum by completing squares.

Comment: Why do you think that the minimum of $x^2(4-2x)^2$ is when $x^2=(4-2x)^2$? I can't see any way of showing that by AM-GM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AM-GM rule is not for a minimum value of a function. It just says that when $$x^2=(4-2x)^2$$
The two sides becomes equal.

You can test it with 
$$y=x^2+1^2 \geq 2|x|$$
If you draw the two curves, you will see the minimum point $(0,1)$ is below the $2$ equability points at $x = \pm 1$.

Hope this explained you question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=x^2+(4-2x)^2=5x^2-16x+16$. We have
$$
5S=25x^2-80x+80=(25x^2-80x+64)+16=(5x-8)^2+16\geq 16.
$$
So $\min(S)=\frac{16}{5}$ which realizes iff $x=\frac{8}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Completing squares seems to be the best way for this, AM-GM does not look natural.  If you do want to use inequalities, Cauchy-Schwarz is a better bet:
$$\left(x^2+(4-2x)^2 \right)(4+1) \ge (2x + \overline{4-2x})^2 = 4^2$$

So $x^2+(4-2x)^2 \ge \frac{16}5$, with equality when $\dfrac{x}2 = 4-2x \implies x = \frac85$.